# Mac style window management on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos

On Macs you can command+tab to select the program you want and then command+~ to cycle through instances of that program you have open. Is there any way to easily replicate that behavior Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You might find that the `ALT` key on a Windows machine is quite similar to the `Command` key shortcut counterparts. In this instance you'll just hold `ALT` and keep pressing tab until the program you wish to bring focus to is selected. You can also click within the selector while ALT is being held.